# JQuery .focus() doesn't place cursor in input

Tags: jquery, forms, input, focus

I know this is a common question but cannot find the answer. Been looking for a long time now.

We have n number of input fields, each with a unique id and name. We are trying to put focus onto the next input when the user tabs. What's happening is the cursor goes to the URL bar instead.

The Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
console.log("main.js called");
var next, nextId;

function hideLabels() {
    $('input').focus(function () {
        var $inputId = $(this).attr('id');
        $('label[for="' + $inputId + '"]').removeClass('hide');
    });

    $('input').focusout(function () {
        var $inputId = $(this).attr('id');
        if ($(this).val().length !== 0) {
            $(this).addClass('set');
            $('label[for="' + $inputId + '"]').addClass('hide');
            next = $(this).next('label').next('input');
            nextId = "#" + next.attr('id');
            $('label[for="' + nextId + '"]').removeClass('hide');
            next.removeClass('hide');
            focusNextInput(nextId);
        } else if ($(this).val().length === 0) {
            $(this).removeClass('set');
            $('label[for="' + $inputId + '"]').removeClass('hide');
        }
    });
}

function focusNextInput (nId) {
    $(nId).css('background', 'red');
    $(nId).focus();
};
});
```

The HMTL:

```
<article>
<label for="input1" class="inputLabel">Label 1</label>
<input type="text" placeholder="a fantabulous placeholder" id="input1" class="form">

<label for="input2" class="inputLabel hide">Label 2</label>
<input type="text" placeholder="a fantabulous placeholder" id="input2" class="form hide">

<label for="input3" class="inputLabel hide">Label 3</label>
<input type="text" placeholder="a fantabulous placeholder" id="input3" class="form hide">

<label for="input4" class="inputLabel hide">Label 4</label>
<input type="text" placeholder="a fantabulous placeholder" id="input4" class="form hide">

<label for="input5" class="inputLabel hide">Label 5</label>
<input type="text" placeholder="a fantabulous placeholder" id="input5" class="form hide">

<label for="input6" class="inputLabel hide">Label 6</label>
<input type="text" placeholder="a fantabulous placeholder" id="input6" class="form hide">

<label for="input7" class="inputLabel hide">Label 7</label>
<input type="text" placeholder="a fantabulous placeholder" id="input7" class="form hide">

<label for="input8" class="inputLabel hide">Label 8</label>
<input type="text" placeholder="a fantabulous placeholder" id="input8" class="form hide">

<label for="input9" class="inputLabel hide">Label 9</label>
<input type="text" placeholder="a fantabulous placeholder" id="input9" class="form hide">
```

Comment: This would appear to be an issue: `$(nId[name=nId]).focus();` What are you expecting that selector to do? Also, where is `hideLabels()` called from?

Comment: Ahh, ignore that. Updated to where we're at right now. If we console log that out we get what we'd expect.